# Problema de consola Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, aplicación-web

estoy empezando a estudiar vue.js, pero tengo un problema, creando la variable lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
var app = new Vue{{
el: '#app',
data {
    message:'hola mundo'
}
```

}};

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aqui pareciera que todo estuviera bien, pero cuando abro el archivo me pasa lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo ese error con los { } y no se a que se puede deber, el problema claramente es en el renglón 1 de app.js

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu problema es de sintaxis, intenta reemplazar las llaves por parentesis en la funcion `Vue`:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data {
      message:'hola mundo'
  }
});
```

Reemplaza `Vue{{` por `Vue({`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya está solucionado. Muy util!!